# How to include android.support in build.gradle using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build.gradle

I work with Android 4.4.2 (API 19) and Eclipse. I use the following build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:19.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

I have the java class

```
package com.example.ejemplo2;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

I get the error in the Eclipse editor

```
android.support cannot resolve
```

How do I have include android.support in build.gradle?. I can't fix this error in Eclipse.

Comment: just don't use eclipse :( its not officially supported any more, why walk into that world of pain

Answer (score 0):

Please use Android Studio... for your own sake.

For what it is worth:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:19.0.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

should be

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
       // NOT HERE
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:19.0.0' // HERE
}
```

The reason is you where adding the support lib as a dependency of the *build script* not a dependency of your java class path

Comment: Another question how  do I can get android-support-v7.jar?